# GWT production crash

Tags: javascript, debugging, gwt

I am developing a GWT-GAE Java trading app, where clients place orders that are processed on a server, which then notifies clients (via AppEngine Channel) of updates. My problem is that I am getting irregular client crashes - after 5~10 minutes of trading, clients may crash (in Chrome I see this page: chrome://crash/). I have tested this in production with up to 10 simultaneous traders (on separate machines) trading for 30 minutes, I usually get 4 or 5 independent client crashes. With fewer connections, or less trading activity, I don't see crashes.

I thought the problem might be ConcurrentModificationExceptions, so I tried 1) using deferred commands with Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred, and 2) implementing a Message queue, but neither of these seem to help.

My question is - how do I debug this? In development, I am limited in the number of simultaneous connections I can make (2 or 3) before I get memory errors, so I can't replicate my problem. Is there a way to see what kind of exceptions are being thrown in production that are causing these crashes?

I had a look at the [GWT logging mechanism](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging) - would I be able to log tab crashes on the server?

Thanks!

### UPDATE

I've setup gwt-log, but when I reproduce my client crash it doesn't seem to log it. It logs all kinds of other info, but no errors when the client crashes. On the client I have a try-catch surrounding the channel messages:

```
try {
  SerializationStreamReader reader = ((SerializationStreamFactory)rpcService).createStreamReader(encodedData);
  Message message = (Message) reader.readObject();
  Log.info(name + ": " + message.toString());
  processMessage(message);
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.fatal(name + ": error encoding " + encodedData);
}
```

Should I be seeing something in the server logs when the client crashes?

Comment: How do you debug: dev-mode or superdev-mode?

Comment: dev-mode, I think (my project is using the default Google Plugin for Eclipse settings).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using [Remote_Logging](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging#Remote_Logging)

There is also https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/

which gives you a few more options such as

- customized url

  https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted#Override_the_default_URL_which_the_RemoteLogger_connects_to
- formatting

  https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted#Server_side_log_messages

  --------------EDIT--------------

  Did you try the UncaughtExceptionHandler?

  //  Install an UncaughtExceptionHandler which will produce `FATAL` log messages

  ```
  Log.setUncaughtExceptionHandler();
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing it now. Will update again after I've fully tested it.

Comment: gwt-log doesn't seem to be able to catch browser tab crashes - it logs other types of messages to the server, but I don't see anything (in the server logs) when the tab crashes.

Comment: try https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted#Setup_an_UncaughtExceptionHandler

Answer (score 0):

Using `dev-mode` you will got soon into memory and performance problems with big apps, or with apps  using a lot of jsni. That is due to the architecture of dev-mode needing complex communication process between the IDE and the browser plugin, and frequent execution context switching between JVM and JS.

To debug complex things, it is better to use the [super-dev mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode), which will execute only javascript in your browser, and offers a nice way ([source-maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)) to debug the app in your browser, but using your java sources.

Note, that super-dev mode setup is a bit more complex, specially when you need to communicate with your backend, reloading process is a bit slower, and be aware that you will miss your IDE java debug console. But it worth a try.